# ASP.NET web page -> Best ways to display static information

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, .net-2.0

I have webpage in the ASP.NET site wherein it shows about 3000 records (the number of records grew substantially after the code logic was written few years back). This page uses Jquery as well.

The display on the page is a tabular format with first column being an image (read from webserver location) and then Item Group and then Item numbers. It uses    and this html is generated on the fly when user navigates to this webpage.

The page has started rendering slowly as number of records have increased.

I am planning to rewrite the logic here. Since the information doesn't change, I am thinking of displaying contents on the page by storing information as html and then just display the html when user navigates to this page. Are there any other better suggestions other than html.

Please suggest what are the best options here.

Comment: I'm confused when you say 'storing information as html'. Do you mean you will store the html on the client, but just hide it or it will only be pulled down from the server and rendered on the page when the user navigates to the page?

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta: I want to store in the server and it show it only user comes to the page. The html will be a formatted (table,tr,td) from the 3000 records. I will generate the html elsewhere (not when user naviages to this page).

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the "page has started rendering slowly as number of records have increased" and you decided to cache the generated HTML on the server and then serving the cached version when requested.

Keep in mind that any number of problems could be the bottleneck that is causing the page to be rendered slowly: Request (DNS lookups), Server (Database, Generating HTML), Response (Network), Render HTML (create DOM).

Before optimizing a specific portion of the app, I would see where the bottleneck actually exists.

I would recommend using the [Timeline in Chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) to see where the bottleneck actually exists.

Personally, I believe the issue is either in the response taking a long time to download (make sure you gzip the response) or in rendering the HTML, but again, without instrumentation, this is just a guess.